# unpin folders in windows (os) quick access using cmd command calling powershell from after effects callsystem

Tags: powershell, cmd, extendscript

anyone could help this out?
Its about powershell use.
Im using inside after effects scripting language: extendscript.

Pinning works, but cant solve unpinning; Tried this and many other ways, before posting.

```
// Pin folder to quick access (working)
    system.callSystem("cmd.exe /c powershell.exe -c \"$qa = New-Object -ComObject shell.application; $qa.NameSpace('C:\\TEST').Self.InvokeVerb(\'pintohome\')\"");

// Unpin folder from quick access (not working):
    system.callSystem("cmd.exe /c powershell.exe -c \"($qa.Namespace(\"shell:::{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}\").Items() | Where-Object { $_.Path -EQ 'C:\\TEST' }).InvokeVerb('unpinfromhome')\"");
```

Tried to follow [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739317/programatically-pin-unpin-the-folder-from-quick-access-menu-in-windows-10) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Your unpin call doesnt define `$qa` - each execution of `system.callSystem()` is starting a new PowerShell instance which is independent. On your attempt to unpin `$qa` will be undefined / `Namespace()` wont exist and it will fail.

Try copying the code `$qa = New-Object -ComObject shell.application;` from the beginning of the pin command and paste it at the beginning of the unpin command like this:

```
system.callSystem("cmd.exe /c powershell.exe -c \"$qa = New-Object -ComObject shell.application; ($qa.Namespace(\"shell:::{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}\").Items() | Where-Object { $_.Path -EQ 'C:\\TEST' }).InvokeVerb('unpinfromhome')\"");
```

Comment: thanks for answering. 
this code works in powershell:
`$qa = New-Object -ComObject shell.application;($qa.Namespace("shell:::{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}").Items() | Where-Object { $_.Path -EQ 'C:\TEST' }).InvokeVerb("unpinfromhome")`
But this one u sent, didnt. Nothing happens. `system.callSystem("cmd.exe /c powershell.exe -c \"$qa = New-Object -ComObject shell.application; ($qa.Namespace(\"shell:::{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}\").Items() | Where-Object { $_.Path -EQ 'C:\\TEST' }).InvokeVerb('unpinfromhome')\"");`

Comment: It must be throwing some runtime error - try adding `Start-Transcript -Path scriptlog.txt;` to the start of the powershell command. That will write all output and errors to the file `scriptlog.txt` - maybe something useful there? (you can edit your question and add more info to the bottom ;-))

Comment: tried some configs and didnt work for me yet