# Is it possible to use a powershell instance inside a .net framework dll?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, dll

As the topic says, i'm trying to intergrate these code from [Programatically Pin\UnPin the folder from quick access menu in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739317/programatically-pin-unpin-the-folder-from-quick-access-menu-in-windows-10) into a .net framework dll.

This is my code and it will throw error "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program."

```cs
private void PinFolderToQuickAccess(string path)
{
    try
    {
        using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runspace.Open();

            var ps = PowerShell.Create();
            var shellApplication =
                ps.AddCommand("New-Object").AddParameter("ComObject", "shell.application").Invoke();

            dynamic nameSpace = shellApplication.FirstOrDefault()?.Methods["NameSpace"].Invoke(path);
            nameSpace?.Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Err: {0}", e);
    }
}

private void UnpinFolderFromQuickAccess(string path)
{
    try
    {
        using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            var ps = PowerShell.Create();
            var removeScript =
                $"((New-Object -ComObject shell.application).Namespace(\"shell:::{{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}}\").Items() | Where-Object {{ $_.Path -EQ \"{path}\" }}).InvokeVerb(\"unpinfromhome\")";

            ps.AddScript(removeScript);
            ps.Invoke();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Err: {0}", e);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void RemoveFromQuickAccess_WithAddFirst()
{
    QuickAccessHandler handler = new QuickAccessHandler();

    string testPath = @"C:\Users\hp\Downloads\Compressed";

    handler.RemoveFromQuickAccess(testPath);
}
```

I have tried another solution from here [Is it possible programmatically add folders to the Windows 10 Quick Access panel in the explorer window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051634/is-it-possible-programmatically-add-folders-to-the-windows-10-quick-access-panel)

but this time it will stuck at `InvokeVerb("pintohome")`

```cs
private void PinFolderToQuickAccess(string path)
{
    try
    {
        Type shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
        Object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
        Shell32.Folder2 f = (Shell32.Folder2)shellAppType.InvokeMember("NameSpace", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[] { path });
        f.Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Err: {0}", e);
    }
}

private void UnpinFolderFromQuickAccess(string path)
{
    try
    {
        Type shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
        Object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
        Shell32.Folder2 f2 = (Shell32.Folder2)shellAppType.InvokeMember("NameSpace", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[] { "shell:::{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}" });
        foreach (FolderItem fi in f2.Items())
        {

            if (fi.Path == path)
            {
                ((FolderItem)fi).InvokeVerb("unpinfromhome");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Err: {0}", e);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use a powershell instance inside a .net framework dll? Or how should it be?

Comment: The link you had referred to a Win95 utility.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3#addscript

Comment: The error message suggests that you're trying to use the _Windows PowerShell_ (.NET Framework) SDK from a .NET (Core) application, which doesn't work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211901/45375) for what PowerShell SDK NuGet package to choose when.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the doc, it seems to better to use the second code.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for your help and i've figured out that's exactly part of the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion, it's totally ok to do it.

In my case, the problem has two effects.

First, i used `System.Management.Automation` directly, which is not recommended. If you're using .net framework, use `Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies` instead.

For more details about it, you should check this answer [How to automate either PowerShell or PowerShell Core for same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211358/how-to-automate-either-powershell-or-powershell-core-for-same-machine/58211901#58211901).

Second, to embed all reference into .exe file, i use `Costura.Fody` to do it which leads to some unexpected problem, like hard to run my code about powershell instance. Not sure why, but just remove it, then everything goes well.