# c# What is Windows 10 QuickAccess Path?

Tags: c#, windows-10, explorer

I need to programmatically access via a button click,  the Quick Access folder on Windows 10.

I haven't figured what is it's phisical location if it has,  or it's alias or symlink.

I know that the method to access any desired folder is the use of **explorer.exe** and use the desired folder as an argument when invoking the method.  This is not my issue and is not the point of this question.

The point of this question is to know which is Windows 10 QuickAccess absolutepath, to use it as an argument within the process.Start method to open the QuickAccess location the same way on does by clicking Windows File Explorer.

```
 Process.Start(@"explorer.exe");
```

Comment: Did they give it a different name?  I remember it as [windows app paths](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+app+paths).

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for a way to programmatically open File Explorer and display the target of a previously-created Quick Access link (which may or may not involve the filesystem location, if one exists, at which Quick Access is stored)?

Comment: Display the default windows 10 QuickAccess link,  or MyPc which shows some folders, Documents, Downloads, ...

Comment: @HansPassant this works fine for applications,  however I'm looking for opening a link or folder that by default, Windows 10 calls either MyPc or QuickAccess, which indeed is opened by invoking explorer.exe.  However I need to specify the Path: C:\Users\<user_name>\...

Answer (score 1):

Information from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30557488/2090467).

You can paste below line to 'Run' in Windows 10 and it will open QuickAccess folder

```
shell:::{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}
```

Tested on Win 10 - works just fine.
I think this string is the closest to QuickAccess absolutepath you've asked for.