# Powershell script to map Quick Access not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to setup Quick Access links in Windows Explorer (Windows 10), but I'm getting an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At C:\scripts\new1.ps1:3 char:1

```
$folder2 = '\\disabilityrightstexas- 
   my.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\personal\' + $env:username + 
   '_disabilityrightstx_org\Documents'
$QuickAccess = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$QuickAccess.Namespace($folder2).Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")
```

Comment: have you researched https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051634/is-it-possible-programmatically-add-folders-to-the-windows-10-quick-access-panel/43658032#43658032?  paths needs to exist and possible this does not work with libraries.

Comment: Looks like I can map to local drives, but not o365 document libraries including OneDrive. I'll need a way to pass credentials before trying to map QuickAccess links.