# How do you get a list of all directories in Windows10 Quick Access c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10-desktop, directoryinfo

I'm trying to get a list of all directories in Windows 10 Quick Access.

by directories, I mean the string(directory) that can be used with

```
foreach (var p in directories)
   {var d = new DirectoryInfo(directory);}
```

this is a c# .net project

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051634/is-it-possible-programmatically-add-folders-to-the-windows-10-quick-access-panel/30557488#30557488) may help

Comment: It's an interesting question. Can I ask why you need this list?

Comment: @Neil. It is a list of common paths used by the user.

Comment: I know what it is. I'm wondering what your purpose is for using it.

Comment: I know what it is. I'm wondering what your purpose is for using it.

Comment: i'm building a dj program. the quick access will provide the user with a quick access to music locations.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from [this case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eef5017b-4132-49ac-8139-66b1da844e6b/windows-10-programmatically-use-quick-access?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues). Currently there is no such api that provide to access `Quick Access` visual folder programmatically .

If you have a platform capability or API suggestion, please continue to post them to the [Windows platform developer UserVoice site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/). Please note that Microsoft will be updating this site to reflect the new capabilities of Windows 10.