# Excel 2016 VBA FilePicker - Code to add Folders to Quick Access Group on Navigation Pane

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, filepicker

I can't find a way to add links of folders (network ones) to the "Quick Access" group in the Navigation Pane of Excel 2016's File or Folder Picker.

I create a File or Folder Picker in VBA, then I assign the most likely useful starting folder to `.InitialFileName` of the Picker object, but then there are another two almost as likely folder paths for the user to start with.

All three starting folder options are a pain to browse, hence the need to stick a link for the other two likely paths somewhere (which are not set at `.InitialFilename`). I could only think of the above described place to have links to the paths.

All help is appreciated...

First I tried to be really clever and judge the most likely path to be used (by the available data at this point of the macro), but all three possible paths are very likely starting points to pick the actual file or folder needed.

Then I went through the Properties of the File and Folder Picker Objects.
I found nothing about customising the Navigation Pane.

I found a way to add entries to Excel Recent Files, but I could only add files to it not folders, and also Recent Files List isn't available in File or Folder Picker.

Comment: You can add Folders to Quick Access via PowerShell: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658032/9538700](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43658032/9538700)

Comment: You're right, it is already possible to do by PowerShell. First time I didn't notice the comment pointing it out, I only saw the Accepted Answer. I would prefer to do it by VBA if possible, so I'll wait a bit more. If no one will know a VBA way to do it, then I guess I'll start reading up on PowerShell, as I don't know anything about it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Did anyone find a way to do it in VBA?  My problem is that all my paths in the Quick Access got changed for some reason and I want to change them all back without having to remove each quick access entry and add it back with the correct path

Comment: @SixSigmaGuy --- Unfortunately no.. Since then I rather made my code to create shortcuts in the working folder of my code, which shortcuts would get removed by my code later on, when they are not needed anymore. This doesn't help you much as you have a very different reason to try to achieve the above. Perhaps thefirst suggestion could help you more through PowerShell, you could probably rewrite existing ones through PowerShell.