# Powershell script to pin folder to Quick Access removes it when folder already pinned

Tags: powershell, windows-11

I have a Powershell script that runs in Windows11 every time a computer loads, to pin a folder to Quick Access. It is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051634/is-it-possible-programmatically-add-folders-to-the-windows-10-quick-access-panel) thread.

It works, however if the user already had the folder pinned, it will remove the folder instead of leaving it in place. Essentially it acts as a toggle.

I've looked around for some documentation on the InvokeVerb() method but have't found anything clear yet.
I would have thought "pintohome" would just leave the pinned folder in place if already there.

Any idea why this is happening? Is it a Windows11 thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight modification from your provided link: Simply check if the pin already exists.

```
$QuickAccess = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$PathToPin = "C:\MyPathToPin"

if(-not ($QuickAccess.Namespace("shell:::{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}").Items() | ? {$_.Path -eq $PathToPin})){$QuickAccess.Namespace($PathToPin).Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")}
```

Comment: Thank you! The "shell:::..." string is a shortcut for the Quick Access folder? This worked great, although I used the more verbose Where-Object instead of the alias "?". I guess my question as to why this stopped working in Windows 11 after upgrade from 10 still stands, but is moot. It could just be a Windows thing...